# Unable to install a dependencies package using my package.json

Tags: json, node.js, package.json

I have a package.json but when I try to run it in my command console I got this error:

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Windows_NT 5.1.2600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4

npm ERR! Invalid version: "0.1"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     F:\UwAmp\www\nodejs\express\npm-debug.log
```

Here's my package.json

```
{
    "name": "Express101",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "This is a practice demo for express node",
    "main": "app.js",
    "author": {
        "name": "Juan Dela Cruz",
        "email": "jdcruz01@gmail.com"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.13.3",
        "jade": "^1.11.0"
    }
}
```

Can you help me with this? It says that I have an error in the version part.

Comment: `Invalid version: "0.1"`, try `version: "0.1.0"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the error message:

> npm ERR! Invalid version: "0.1"

In your `package.json`, you have this:

> "version": "0.1",`

You need to format this to meet the semver requirements (see the npm [package.json docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#version) and the [node-semver repo](https://github.com/npm/node-semver)).  Add a `0` in front (`0.0.1`) and your error should vanish.

Comment: Thanks for the guidelines and for the answer. I really dont know that package.json has a requirements. :)